# Prove the dominant eigenvalue of a non-negative matrix A is bounded by its maximum and minimum column sums

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The original question is from http://www.prenhall.com/bretscher1e/html/proj10.html and it states:

> Algebra problem: prove if A is nonegative and has dominant eigenvalue
>   e1 and dominant eigenvector x0 (which you may assume has all positive
>   entries) then e1 is in between the largest of the column sums of A and
>   the smallest. (hint: scale x0 so its components add up to 1, then look
>   at the definition of eigenvalue/vector) Examine the problem in the
>   discussion of this project for an example.

**Here is what I have so far:**
Ax=ex
By the property that a scalar multiple of an eigenvector of A has the same corresponding eigenvalue, I can scale x so that its components add to one for some scalar c.
Define CS<sub>A</sub>(n) to be the sum of every component in the n<sup>th</sup> column vector of A.
**Now expanding Ax=ex and adding every equation, I get:**
**(1)** CS<sub>A</sub>(1)x<sub>1</sub> + CS<sub>A</sub>(2)x<sub>2</sub> + CS<sub>A</sub>(3)x<sub>3</sub> + ... + CS<sub>A</sub>(n)x<sub>n</sub> = e
**(2)** x<sub>1</sub> + x<sub>2</sub> + x<sub>3</sub> + ... + x<sub>n</sub> = 1
A dominant e implies that **(1)** is maximized subject to the constraint **(2)**, which means that x<sub>j</sub> is the largest when CS<sub>A</sub>(j) is the largest. I have no idea how to determine that CS<sub>A</sub>(j) is the upper bound for e, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n} \text{CS}_A(k)x_k \le \sum_{k=1}^{n}\max_{1\le \ell\le n} \text{CS}_A(\ell)x_k = \max_{1\le \ell\le n} \text{CS}_A(\ell)\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_k = \max_{1\le \ell\le n} \text{CS}_A(\ell).
$$

Comment: Thank you very much! That was just the direction I needed.